# Transform select into ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the size options in my product page that looks like:

```
<select class="super-attribute-select">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="12" price="1.99">38 +1.99</option>
    <option value="9" price="3.98">39 +3.98</option>
    <option value="10" price="5.97">40 +5.97</option>
    <option value="11" price="7.96">41 +7.96</option>
    <option value="8" price="9.95">42 +9.95</option>
</select>
```

I need to transform it into ul li a list, with same size value, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Choose an Option...</a>
    <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">39</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">40</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">41</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">42</a></li>
</ul>
```

and when i click on some ul li a size same size (option) must be chosen in select tag.

Comment: Why can't you use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin? You can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".super-attribute-select option").each(function(){
        $("#select").append('<li><a href="#">' + $(this).html() + '</a></li>');
    });
    $("#select").on("click", "li a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".super-attribute-select").val($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/nqenx5zh/2/

Comment: Read the last line of the question one more time.

Comment: I think Select2 plugin will help me a lot, ty for advise and code example!